# What is the boolean interpolation character for string.format function in lua

Tags: string, lua, boolean

I'm looking for a boolean interpolation character for `string.format`(as the title says).
I want something that will work this way:

```
print(string.format("nil == false: %b",(nil==false))
```

%b is just a placeholder, you'll get an error with that. I'm looking for 'b'. I can't
just do:

```
print("nil == false: " .. (nil==false))
```

because booleans can't be concatenated with strings. I could do:

```
val=(nil==false)
if val==false then truth="false" else truth="true" end
print("nil==false: ".. truth)
```

But it's too much work.

Comment: What about `print("nil == false: " .. tostring(nil==false))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wondering how to modify `string.format` so it supports bools, here's one way you can do it:

```
do
local format = string.format
function string.format(str, ...)
  local args = {...}
  local boolargs = {}
  str = str:gsub("%%b", "%%%%b")
  for i = #args, 1, -1 do
    if type(args[i]) == "boolean" then
      table.insert(boolargs, 1, args[i])
      table.remove(args, i)
    end
  end
  str = format(str, unpack(args))

  local j = 0
  return (str:gsub("%%b", function(spec) j = j + 1; return tostring(boolargs[j]) end))
end
end

print(string.format("%s is %b", "nil == false", nil==false))
```

It might be a bit confusing to follow. The idea is to gsub all "%b" in the string and replace it with double escape `%%b` so format doesn't try to interpret it. We let `string.format` do its stuff and we take the result and handle `%b` manually ourselves.

Comment: @Segfault The actual items that maps to the format specs is in the `...` part passed in. We have to remove all the bools from that before giving it to the real `string.format`. But we also need to keep those removed bools around so we know what to substitute in later. The varargs `...` isn't a first-class construct in lua so I wrapped it into a table to make it easier to manipulate.

Comment: I must say, your answer is impressive to say the least. Why is it that `g=...` stores the first argument passed to the function while `f={...}` stores the arg table. Also, why did you do `local args={...}` yet there's already an implicit `arg` table being passed?

Comment: I got that part, thanks. What I meant was for example, this:  

    `function func(...)
        g=...
        f={...}
        print(f) -- table: 0076B070
        print(g) -- "first arg"
    end
    func("first arg","second arg")`

Why aren't `f` and `g` the same? Value adjustment?

Comment: @Segfault that's because `f = {...}` creates a new table in the process of wrapping the arguments. OTOH `g = ...`, the right-hand side has 1 or more arguments but the left hand side can only fit one argument. If you had say `g, h, i = ...` then you take the first 3 arguments from the right side and put each of them into `g, h, i` respectively.

Answer (score 6):

Well, first you should try reading [the relevant section of the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format). That will let you discover that there is no format specifier for booleans.

What greatwolf suggests is a solution, i.e. converting the value explicitly to a string. If there is a possibility that your truth value may be `nil`, but you want to output it as `false`, this trick is useful:

```
truth = nil
print("nil==false: ".. tostring( not not truth ))
```

In this way both `nil` and `false` will be displayed as `false`.

**Edit** (to answer a comment)

In Lua 5.2 the `%s` specifier automatically convert the arguments to strings using `tostring` internally. Thus:

```
print( string.format( "%s  %s  %s", true, nil, {} ) )
```

prints:

```
true  nil  table: 00462400
```

otherwise you can create your own formatting function wrapping `string.format`:

```
 local function myformat( fmt, ... )
    local buf = {}
     for i = 1, select( '#', ... ) do
         local a = select( i, ... )
         if type( a ) ~= 'string' and type( a ) ~= 'number' then
             a = tostring( a )
         end
         buf[i] = a
     end
     return string.format( fmt, unpack( buf ) )
 end


 print( myformat( "%s  %s  %s", true, nil, {} ) )
```

Comment: That's fair enough, considering it's shorter than the alternatives. I'm curious though, is it possible to add/extend `string.format` with a new character for booleans using `C` or `C++`?

Comment: @Sefault of course it's possible but a bit involved. see my response for one way to do it.

Comment: @Segfault If your C-language skills are good you could modify the sources. A simpler approach is shown in my edit above. If you really want a new format specifier, see the answer of greatwolf, but it is a bit overkill IMHO.

Comment: Your approach seems to work. What does `select` do? The lua reference is not very helpful. Also, why is @greatwolf's answer overkill? It's quite impressive and clever IMO.

Comment: @Segfault the `select` function provides some conveniences for working with varargs passed in. `select('#', ...)` returns the argument count for the `...` part. `select(i, ...)` returns the i'th element and onwards.

Comment: @Segfault I completely agree with you about greatwolf's cleverness. When I said "overkill" I meant that such an effort is not probably worth the problem at hand. As a proof of concept or as an example of useful techniques it is terrific, but in this context is like shooting a fly with a cannon (that's not greatwolf's fault, of course). I'm questioning if it is really worth all the fuss and the clutter just to be able to have a format specifier for bools. And keep in mind that Lua 5.2 `%s` handles all conversions.

Comment: I've finally 'deciphered' your answer. For those who'll study this answer, I'd like to tell you that `select` does not return a table holding the list of arguments(if you thought so). It just returns the list of arguments(separated by a comma I think) such that `local a = select( i, ... )` actually stores the first value passed in the variable the same way `g=...` works.